# CakePHP + nginx 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

I've been trying to install CakePHP on nginx, but I've hit a dead end. I am receiving a 500 internal server error when attempting to access the web root. I am getting this error in my error.log:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/test/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/test/config/bootstrap.php on line 23" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: , server: example.com,
>   request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"

If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be great. Thank you!

Comment: This says it all: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/test/vendor/autoload.php

Comment: Wrong Installation + No Permission = Internal Server Error

Comment: Yeah I was confused as to why I was missing it, @MrTechie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was missing php5-intl. Solved.